# C++ Playing Card Class

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, class

I'm trying to create a program that will have a class for a playing card, However I'm running into an "uninitialized local variable 'suit' used " error. I cannot for the life of me figure out why, as I thought the default construct would initilize the variables for me. 
I put my code below to describe my problem.

```
#include "Card.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
Card Hand('D','H');

Hand.getSuit();

return 0;
}
```

This is my driver that should be running the class. 
Here is my program file:

```
#include "Card.h"   
#include <iostream>      
#include <cstdlib>       
#include <string>
using namespace std;

Card::Card()
{
suit = 'H';
rank = '1';
worth = 1;
}

Card::Card(char b , char h)
{
suit = 'H';
rank = 'H';
worth = 1;
}

char getSuit(){
char suit = suit;
cout << suit;
return suit;
}
```

And here is my header file:

```
 #ifndef CARD_H
#define CARD_H

class Card
{
private:
  char suit;
  char rank;
  int worth;

public:
  Card::Card();
  Card::Card(char, char );

  char getSuit();
  char getRank();
  int getWorth();

};
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

```
char getSuit(){
    char suit = suit;
    cout << suit;
    return suit;
}
```

You forgot to tell it was a member from `Card`. It should be:

```
char Card::getSuit(){
    char suit = suit;
    cout << suit;
    return suit;
}
```

Moreover - thanks Anton -, naming a local variable `suit` is not a good pratice since it is not clear anymore whether you want to use the class attribute `suit` or the local variable `suit`. You should either change its name or specify when you are using the class attribute with `this->suit` (first option is better).

Comment: Also I would call it bad practice to name both the local variable, and the class variable in one function 'suit'. Makes it hell of a lot confusing...

Comment: Yes, that needs some `this` or some other name. I will complete.

Comment: Just remove the `char suit = suit;` and then it's fine.

Comment: I can't believe I forgot something so obvious. The whole suit = suit thing was just an attempt to try to get the program to initialize.

Comment: @user2105982 Well, the more obvious it is, the less we see it, right?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify that getSuit is part of Card class

```c
char Card::getSuit()
```

Also :

```
char getSuit(){
    char suit = suit;
    cout << suit;
    return suit;
}
```

You are assigning suit to suit. Try to use `char suit = this.suit;` Or you could rename the local suit variable.